# Creating a new column when values in another column is not duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
       'a': [98, 97, 100, 101, 103, 110, 108, 109, 130, 135],
       'b': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       'c': [np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0],
       'd': [92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92, 92],
    }
)
```

And this is the expected output. I want to to create column `x`:

```
     a  b    c   d    x
0   98  3  NaN  92   92
1   97  3  NaN  92   92
2  100  3  1.0  92   94
3  101  3  1.0  92   94
4  103  3  1.0  92   94
5  110  3  2.0  92  104
6  108  3  2.0  92  104
7  109  3  2.0  92  104
8  130  3  3.0  92  124
9  135  3  3.0  92  124
```

Steps:

a) When `c` is not duplicated, `df['x'] = df.a - (df.b * 2)`

b) If `df.c == np.nan`, `df['x'] = df.d`

For example:

The first new value in `c` is row `2`. So `df['x'] = 100 - (3 * 2)` which is 94 and `df['x'] = 94` until a new value in `c` appears which is row `5`. For row `5`, `df['x'] = 110 - (3 * 2)` which is 104. And the logic continues.

This is what I have tried:

```
df['x'] = df.a - (df.b * 2)
df.loc[df.c.isna(), 'x'] = df.d
df['x'] = df.x.cummax()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html), [`grouby.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
# identify duplicated "c"
m = df['c'].duplicated()

# compute a-(2*b)
# mask the duplicated "c"
# ffill per group
# replace NaN with "d"
df['x'] = (df['a'].sub(df['b'] * 2)
           .mask(m)
           .groupby(df['c']).ffill()
           .fillna(df['d'])
          )
```

Variant to work by groups of successive identical "c":

```
g = df['c'].ne(df['c'].shift()).cumsum()
m = g.duplicated()
df['x'] = (df['a'].sub(df['b'] * 2)
           .mask(m)
           .groupby(m1.cumsum()).ffill()
           .where(df['c'].notna(), df['d'])
          )
```

Output:

```
     a  b    c   d      x
0   98  3  NaN  92   92.0
1   97  3  NaN  92   92.0
2  100  3  1.0  92   94.0
3  101  3  1.0  92   94.0
4  103  3  1.0  92   94.0
5  110  3  2.0  92  104.0
6  108  3  2.0  92  104.0
7  109  3  2.0  92  104.0
8  130  3  3.0  92  124.0
9  135  3  3.0  92  124.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```py
mask = ~df["c"].isna()

df["x"] = (
    df[mask]
    .groupby(
        (df.loc[mask, "c"] != df.loc[mask, "c"].shift()).cumsum(), group_keys=False
    )
    .apply(
        lambda x: pd.Series(
            [x["a"].iat[0] - (x["b"].iat[0] * 2)] * len(x), index=x.index
        )
    )
)
df.loc[~mask, "x"] = df["d"]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     a  b    c   d      x
0   98  3  NaN  92   92.0
1   97  3  NaN  92   92.0
2  100  3  1.0  92   94.0
3  101  3  1.0  92   94.0
4  103  3  1.0  92   94.0
5  110  3  2.0  92  104.0
6  108  3  2.0  92  104.0
7  109  3  2.0  92  104.0
8  130  3  3.0  92  124.0
9  135  3  3.0  92  124.0
```